# C replacement of & in c++

Tags: c++, c, list, replace

i'm trying to create a function in C to pass the K from last node and i'm having difficulty to find a replacement for the **&** operator in **c++** which is a reference.
i understand that im supposed to switch the **&** with a * but it still doesnt seem to work for me.

```
my_node *k_to_last(my_node * head, int k, int *pos)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    my_node *current = k_to_last(head->next,k, &pos);
    pos++;
    if (pos == k)
        return head;
    return current;
}

int main ()
{
    int k;
    int pos = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the K node: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("\nthe %d node value from last is: %d\n", k_to_last(head, k, &pos)->value);
    return 0;
}
```

thanks for any help in advance, and please ignore minor issues such as using scanf instead of fget, etc...

Edit: much thanks to "JeremyP" for his answer
the fixed code:

```
my_node *k_to_last(my_node * head, int k, int *pos)
{
if (head == NULL)
    return NULL;
my_node *current = k_to_last(head->next, k, pos);
(*pos)++;
if (k == *pos)
    return head;
return current;
}

int main()
{
    int k;
    int pos = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the K node: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("\nthe %d node value from last is: %d\n", k, k_to_last(head, k, &pos)->value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn you about this `if (pos == k)`?

Comment: @alk I'd be surprised. The fragment posted has way more problems than just comparing an `int` to a pointer.

Comment: `k_to_last(head->next,k, &pos);` should be `k_to_last(head->next,k, pos);` because at that point `pos` is already a pointer. `pos++` increments value of pointer, not a value it points to, you need to dereference it instead `++(*pos)` . same with `pos == k`. I think you are getting confused because you use name `pos` for an `int` variable and for a pointer to an `int` variable. Name pointer something like `p_pos` instead.

Comment: Here's where I have trouble following. You need to create a function in C. So what does C++ and references have to do with it? What are you really asking about?

Comment: _replacement for the & operator in c++ which is a reference_ what? You can compile C code that uses pointer with C++ without changing any '&'-

Comment: The `&` *operator* is the "address-of" operator that C++ inherited from C. (The symbol has different meanings in types and expressions.)

Comment: Some `{}` would be nice.

Comment: @StoryTeller C++ has a thing that C doesn't have called references. A reference is like a pointer but syntactically, you use references the same way as the dereferenced object. References are denoted in declarations with the `&` sign where the `*` would be in a pointer declaration.

Comment: @JeremyP - [Thanks for the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/c?userid=817643) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` in this context means "pointer". Unlike a C++ reference, pointers which are sort of like DIY references do not get dereferenced automatically. So in the declaration

```
my_node *k_to_last(my_node * head, int k, int *pos)
```

`pos` is a pointer (and so is `head`). When you want to access the `int` it references, you must explicitly dereference it e.g.

```
if (k == *pos) // Note the *
{
    // do somenthing
}
(*pos)++; // increment the int to which pos points
```

Also, to pass an `int` to the function for `pos` you must take its address with the `&` operator.

```
int pos = 0;
my_node head; // Gloss over the fact that this is uninitialised
k_to_last(&head, k, &pos);
```

But inside the function, since `pos` is already a pointer, you do not need to take its address for parameters that require an `int*`, for example, when calling the function recursively.

```
my_node *k_to_last(my_node * head, int k, int *pos)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    my_node *current = k_to_last(head->next,k, pos); // no & needed here
}
```